# DynamicObject binding WRT private types

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Consider the following:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace DynamicTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic d = new DynamicTest();
            var v = d.foo();
            Console.WriteLine(v.Value);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public interface IValueProvider<T>
    {
        T Value
        {
            get;
        }
    }

    public class DynamicTest : DynamicObject
    {
        public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
        {
            result = new ValueProvider<int>(32);
            return true;
        }

        private class ValueProvider<T> : IValueProvider<T>
        {
            public ValueProvider(T t)
            {
                this.Value = t;
            }

            public T Value
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fails at runtime with:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException was unhandled
  Message='object' does not contain a definition for 'Value'
  Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
  StackTrace:
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
       at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
       at DynamicTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

If I change the `ValueProvider<T>` class to `public` rather than `private` it works as expected:

```
// this allows it to work
public class ValueProvider<T> : IValueProvider<T>
```

Or, instead, if I cast the result to `IValueProvider<int>` it also works:

```
// this also allows it to work
dynamic d = new DynamicTest();
var v = (IValueProvider<int>)d.foo();
```

If I try using the interface as the compile-time type in `TryInvokeMember`, it doesn't work (didn't really expect it to, but thought I'd try):

```
// this doesn't help
public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
{
    var valueProvider = (IValueProvider<int>)new ValueProvider<int>(32);
    result = valueProvider;
    return true;
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing here? Is there a way for me to get the code above working without resorting to making all my types public and without casting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, it works if the accessibility is `internal`:

```
internal class ValueProvider<T> : IValueProvider<T> { ... }
```

which as Hassan notes (comments) makes sense, as that is the accessibility that would normally be required for `Program` to use the API members of `DynamicTest` (in the same assembly). If we move `Main` to `DynamicTest` and leave it `private` it again works, which is the correct accessibility we should expect.

Maybe use `internal` for now.

Of course, an even better approach here would be to just use the interface. IMO you don't *need* `dynamic` here; what you perhaps need is a non-generic `IValueProvider`:

```
public interface IValueProvider
{
    object Value { get; }
}
public interface IValueProvider<T> : IValueProvider
{
    new T Value{get; }
}
```

with (in the class):

```
object IValueProvider.Value { get { return Value; } }
```

and:

```
var v = (IValueProvider)d.foo();
Console.WriteLine(v.Value);
```

Comment: Why is it strange to you, that internal is working? It looks quite simple to me - it works, if the calling code has access to the class of the returned object.

Comment: @Hassan - yes, fair enough - it is being more subtle (and correct) than I gave it credit - I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make `ValueProvider<T>` inherit `DynamicObject` aswell, and then implementing `TryGetMember` on that:

```
        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            result = this.Value;
            return true;
        }
```

of course in this example we're just returning the Value no matter what property you try to get, but I'd probably look into using a dictionary or an ExpandoObject to keep the available properties on `ValueProvider<T>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, my example is highly simplified. My interface is quite complex - it does far more than just return a value.