# Why won't the DLR (dynamic) bind to a private type?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Consider the following program:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Tests
    {
        public static void Test<T>(T value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
        }

        public static void TestReflection(object value)
        {
            typeof(Tests).GetMethod("Test")
                .MakeGenericMethod(value.GetType())
                .Invoke(null, new [] { value });
        }

        public static void TestDynamic(object value)
        {
            Test((dynamic)value);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Tests.Test(new MyPublicType());
            Tests.Test(new MyPrivateType());

            Console.WriteLine();

            Tests.TestReflection(new MyPublicType());
            Tests.TestReflection(new MyPrivateType());

            Console.WriteLine();

            Tests.TestDynamic(new MyPublicType());
            Tests.TestDynamic(new MyPrivateType());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class MyPublicType {}

        private class MyPrivateType : MyPublicType {}
    }
}
```

The results in the output:

```
MyPublicType
MyPrivateType

MyPublicType
MyPrivateType

MyPublicType
MyPublicType
```

You can see that generics can handle private types and reflection can handle private types, but dynamic upcasts my private type to a public type. Why does it do this? Is this behavior documented somewhere?

I was just trying to avoid the crufty reflection code when calling the generic method dynamically. I wanted the exact type to match because I was retrieving attributes on the type and caching them in a generic static class to avoid a dictionary / lock pattern.

Comment: I believe the issue there is mix of `dynamic` only exposing public types/methods (otherwise it would bypass all type safety) and the fact you are using generics to show class name and not `value.GetType().Name`... Can't find good links for first part so - maybe someone had one handy. (Here is somewhat related post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145029/dynamicobject-binding-wrt-private-types?rq=1)

Comment: Looks like it's purely related to the fact it is a nested private class. If you take them out of the `Program` class, it works and if you remove the inheritance while it's nested it just gets converted to `Object`. I am guessing it just can't access the type it needs for some reason.

Comment: @TyCobb True - you can only define private types at the class level. If I do an internal type at the namespace level, it works.

Comment: From Eric Lippert -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338429/c-sharp-dynamic-type-gotcha

Comment: Link provided by @TyCobb has perfect explanation by Eric Lippert - I think it covers whole problem (so using as duplicate). Hopefully better title of this one will help future users to find that explanation.

Comment: Yep, his first sentence kind of explains why it behaves this way. Makes sense now.